# How can i give data attribute variable inside the double quotes using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm Working on the slider.
If I type manually the number on the input box, It will go to the particular slide.

Once I type the value in the input box, I got the value in query variable.

```
$(".slide_keyUp").change(function(){
    var slideNo = $(this).val(); 
    $('"#slider ul li[data-value='+ slideNo +']"').prependTo("#slider ul");
 })
```

IN the above `slideNo` variable I got the value.

**My Problem**

If i give manually value, Its working.

```
$("#slider ul li[data-value='0']").prependTo('#slider ul');
```

But If I give variable inside the double quotes, it is not working

```
$('"#slider ul li[data-value='+ slideNo +']"').prependTo("#slider ul");
```

Many thanks

Comment: 1. Did you test (ie. use `console.log({slideNo})`) to see if the value is defined? 2. Did you mean `prependTo()` instead?

Comment: Yes, I checked in `console.log()`, I got the value.

Comment: preoendTo check is this prependTo

Comment: you have a typo error ! change `preoendTo`  to `prependTo`

Comment: Can you create a minimal working example? What is the error?

Comment: `$("#slider ul li[data-value='"+ slideNo +"']").prependTo("#slider ul");`

Comment: @scraaappy still not working,

Comment: @Steve It's Working, Thank you so much

Comment: @isherwood, I agree and had made an answer immediately following, with the intention of deleting the comment.  when I got done drafting I realized someone had essentially answered the same way.  I deleted my answer, and upvoted theirs.  In future I will refrain from the quick comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There are few syntax errors in your code. Try changing prepend code from**

```
 $('"#slider ul li[data-value='+ slideNo +']"').preoendTo("#slider ul");
```

**to**

```
 $('#slider ul li[data-value="'+ slideNo +'"]').prependTo("#slider ul");
```